# How to create new NoteBook with OneNote API

Tags: c#, post, onenote

I'm getting a "Bad Request" error 400 when I try to create a new Notebook.  Below is my code, I think it is the PagesEndPoint Uri but I have tried all combinations. I can use the apigee console app, but cannot detemine how to make a C# Windows app Post message.

```
async public Task<StandardResponse> CreateNewNotebook(string newNotebookName)
        {

            Uri PagesEndPoint = new Uri("https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks?notebookName="+newNotebookName.ToString());
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            if (IsAuthenticated)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authClient.Session.AccessToken);
            }

            string date = GetDate();
            string simpleHtml = "<html>"+"<head>"+"<title>A simple page created with an image1 on it</title>" +"<meta name=\"created\" content=\"" + date + "\" />" +
                                "</head>" +"<body>" +"<h1>This is a page with an image on it</h1>" +"</body>" +"</html>";
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            HttpRequestMessage createMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, PagesEndPoint)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(simpleHtml, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
            };

            response = await client.SendAsync(createMessage);
            tbResponse.Text = response.ToString();
            return await TranslateResponse(response);


        }
```

I've tried with this new code, but still not working.   The links to the documentation show the elements to use, but not how to use them to make C# method.

Here is my latest code.

```
async public Task<StandardResponse> CreateJsonNotebook(string newNotebookName)
        {

            string postData = "{name: \"NewNotebookName\"}";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            if (IsAuthenticated)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authClient.Session.AccessToken);
            }

           StreamWriter requestWriter;
           var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks") as HttpWebRequest;

           HttpResponseMessage response;
           response = await client.SendAsync(postData);
           tbResponse.Text = response.ToString();
           return await TranslateResponse(response);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

there are a few things incorrect with your latest code pasted above. 
Here's the modified version that I got working :

```
    public async Task<StandardResponse> CreateJsonNotebook(string newNotebookName)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string postData = "{name: \"" + newNotebookName + "\"}";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        if (IsAuthenticated)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                _authClient.Session.AccessToken);
        }

        StreamWriter requestWriter;
        var webRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks")
        {

            Content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = await client.SendAsync(webRequest);
        return await TranslateResponse(response);
    }
```

Notice that:

- I didn't combine usage of HttpClient and HttpWebRequest.
- When creating the HttpWebRequest.Content, I set the mediaType to "application/json"
- Also client.SendAsync() used the HttpRequestMessage and not the postData string.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - the URL isn't quite right. You can't actually create a page and a notebook at the same time - they require two different calls.

To create a notebook, the URL you should post to is:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks
```

The notebook is created with the content of the body, which should be JSON. (Make sure you include `CONTENT-TYPE: application/json` in the header).

The body should look like:

```
{
  name: "New Notebook Name"
}
```

You can then create a section in the notebook with the ID in the response. Once you get the ID of a new section, you can then post a page to that section.

More information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790583(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I tried to reconstruct the code, but not still not working.  Appreciated the links to the documentation, but it just shows the components for the POST, never how to construct the message and send it to the web service.  Here is my latest coded.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling the API is incorrect. You shouldn't be putting a notebookName query parameter in the endpoint. Instead, you should just post to https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks with a JSON body. The JSON body should be

{ name: "New notebook name" }

You can see this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/08/04/new-apis-available-create-notebooks-and-sections.aspx) for an example.

-- James