# How to create a new notebook or section using C# OneNote 2013 15.0 COM Type Library?

Tags: c#, office-interop, onenote

I'm not able to create a new notebook or create a new section in an existing notebook using the OneNote 2013 Developer Reference.

The guidance on [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx) indicates that it is possible, but provides no examples of how to do it.

Whenever I try to add a new notebook, I get an [HRESULT: 0x80042015 error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff966472%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that indicates the notebook does not exist.  I know!  I'm trying to add it :-)

Also, whenever I try to add a new section to an existing notebook, I get an HRESULT: 0x80042014 error code, which indicates the object does not exist.

Here's a code snippet showing what I'm trying to do.  Any help would be appreciated!

```js
try
{
    _app.GetHierarchy(null, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsNotebooks, out strXml);
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(strXml))
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stringReader);

        // Get the first notebook.  Currently, I couldn't find a way to create a new Notebook using the OneNote interops.
        var notebook = xdoc.Root.Descendants().First();
        if (!notebook.Descendants().Any(d => d.Name == "My New Section"))
        {
            // Get ready to create a new section
            XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote";
            var myNewSectionElement = new XElement(ns + "Section");
            myNewSectionElement.Add(new XAttribute("name", "My New Section"));
            myNewSectionElement.Add(new XAttribute("path", @"C:\MyNewSection.one"));
            myNewSectionElement.Add(new XAttribute("ID", @"{5F786510-79D4-4D0B-BC93-A637700D7543}{1}{B0}"));
            notebook.Add(myNewSectionElement);

            // Update the heirarchy
            var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder))
            {
                xdoc.Save(stringWriter);
                _app.UpdateHierarchy(strBuilder.ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.XMLSchema.xs2013);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Output = "My New Section already exists.\r\n";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Output = string.Format("{0}:{1}\r\n", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create new NoteBook with OneNote API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272434/how-to-create-new-notebook-with-onenote-api)

Comment: @Eugene, this question is not the same as the one that you are linking. This question was for the OneNote 2013 Interop library, and not for the OneNote REST APIs. That behavior is more suited for "connected" app development or the metro app development style, whereas mine is for desktop app development with Office 2013 installed on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that my approach to the problem was incorrect.  I thought that if I edited the xml data to include a new Notebook or Section, that the COM library would be smart enough to detect the newly added element(s).  After further reading, the correct way to create a new Notebook or Section is to use the OpenHierarchy() method.

Here is a working copy of me creating a new Section to an existing Notebook.  I have not tried creating a new Notebook yet, but I assume the methodology is similar.

```js
private void DoOpenHierarchy(Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope scope)
{
    Output = "Open Hierarchy Section...\r\n";
    var strXml = string.Empty;
    var objectId = string.Empty;
    _app.GetHierarchy(null, scope, out strXml);
    try
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(strXml);
        var ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
        if (scope == Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsSections)
        {
            var noteBook = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Notebook").FirstOrDefault();
            if (noteBook != null)
            {
                var sectionName = "My New Section";
                Output += string.Format("Attempting to create section '{0}' in {1}...\r\n", sectionName, noteBook.Attribute("name").Value);
                var location = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.one", noteBook.Attribute("path").Value, sectionName);
                _app.OpenHierarchy(location, string.Empty, out objectId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.CreateFileType.cftSection);
                Output += string.Format("Section ID Created: {0}\r\n", objectId.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Output += "ERROR: Not able to determine a 'path' in order to store new section.\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Output += string.Format("{0}:{1}\r\n", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
    }
    Output += "\r\nOpen Hierarchy Section Done.\r\n";
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272434/how-to-create-new-notebook-with-onenote-api

Comment: @Eugene, this question is not the same as the one that you are linking.  This question was for the OneNote 2013 Interop library, and not for the OneNote REST APIs.  That behavior is more suited for "connected" app development or the metro app development style, whereas mine is for desktop app development with Office 2013 installed on the device.